# Django User to User Messaging ModelForm Setup

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to build my own custom user to user messaging app for my site.  I know about Postman and the other ones, but I'm doing my own for two reasons: 1. Get more familiar with Django, 2. Include the possibility for further customization down the road.  As such, I'm trying to create a simple model and ModelForm to use but I'm getting an error.  The following is my code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from home.models import Profile

class Message(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name = 'recipient')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'sender')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, blank = True)
    message = models.TextField()
    sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    unread = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Message from ' + str(self.sender) + '.  Subject:' + str(self.subject)
```

For completeness the home.models Profile class is below, though this is not the problem.

**home.models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from messenger.models import Message

class MessageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('recipient','sender','subject','message','unread')
```

I'm simply trying to figure out how to filter and pull all messages where the "current user" is in a recipient list by defining the queryset in the get method of the view.    The problem is I'm having trouble performing this query and all of the questions I find on Stack Overflow are either older (circa 2013) or I don't see how they directly address my issue.

I've tried using the shell and searching on things like

```
message = Message.objects.first()
message.recipient.all()
```

which shows the following

```
<QuerySet [<Profile: jeff>, <Profile: joe>, <Profile: billy>]>
```

which almost seems to indicate that the constituent objects of the queryset are all objects of the Profile class, but when I try to do a search on something like this:

```
Message.objects.filter(recipient__profiles__in='billy')
```

I get the following error:

```
raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: profiles
```

I've tried many different paths to no avail and I think I'm just not understanding the search functionality.  Essentially all I'm trying to do is create an inbox (find all messages where the current user is in the recipient list) and after quite a while looking online I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
Message.objects.filter(recipient__user__username__in=['billy'])
```